# Error in Updating data, caused by unknown column in Laravel REST API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, crud

I already finished the create and read in my laravel rest api project.

> But when I tried to test the "PUT" method for updating it shown me an
>   error. The error itself i dont know how to resolve that bcs I am still
>   new to laravel. My table name is "tb_peminjaman", but the update
>   method read it as a column of its table. Anyway, I didn't create the
>   tables using migration cause I have my own table created directly
>   using phpmyadmin, so basically the migration filled with default
>   value.

[Here is the Screenshot of my Error shown by Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCOCM.png)>

"I've tried to change my code also disable the timestamps because it could be caused any error for my project. Here I show you my Update code in controller."

```
public function updatePinjam(Request $request, $id){
        if(Pinjam::where('no_pengajuan',$id)->exists()){
            $pinjam = Pinjam::find($id);
            $pinjam->ketua_kegiatan = is_null($request->ketua_kegiatan) ? $pinjam->ketua_kegiatan : $request->ketua_kegiatan;
            $pinjam->lab = is_null($request->lab) ? $pinjam->lab : $request->lab;
            $pinjam->level = is_null($request->level) ? $pinjam->level : $request->level;
            $pinjam->tanggal_mulai = is_null($request->tanggal_mulai) ? $pinjam->tanggal_mulai : $request->tanggal_mulai;
            $pinjam->tanggal_selesai = is_null($request->tanggal_selesai) ? $pinjam->tanggal_selesai : $request->tanggal_selesai;
            $pinjam->jam_mulai = is_null($request->jam_mulai) ? $pinjam->jam_mulai : $request->jam_mulai;
            $pinjam->jam_selesai = is_null($request->jam_selesai) ? $pinjam->jam_selesai : $request->jam_selesai;
            $pinjam->daftar_nama = is_null($request->daftar_nama) ? $pinjam->daftar_nama : $request->daftar_nama;
            $pinjam->keperluan = is_null($request->keperluan) ? $pinjam->keperluan : $request->keperluan;
            $pinjam->kontak_ketua = is_null($request->kontak_ketua) ? $pinjam->kontak_ketua : $request->kontak_ketua;
            $pinjam->app_laboran = is_null($request->app_laboran) ? $pinjam->app_laboran : $request->app_laboran;
            $pinjam->app_kalab = is_null($request->app_kalab) ? $pinjam->app_kalab : $request->app_kalab;
            $pinjam->app_kajur = is_null($request->app_kajur) ? $pinjam->app_kajur : $request->app_kajur;
            $pinjam->app_pudir = is_null($request->app_pudir) ? $pinjam->app_pudir : $request->app_pudir;
            $pinjam->save();
            return response()->json([
            "message" => "Perubahan Berhasil DiLakukan!"
        ], 200);
        } else {
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Pinjam not found"
        ], 404);
    }
    }
```

**And here is the ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;tb_peminjaman.id&#039; in &#039;where clause&#039; (SQL: select * from `tb_peminjaman` where `tb_peminjaman`.`id` = 15 limit 1) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\coba_api_laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 664
```

Please kindly help me to solve this Error, cause this is an important thing for me to continue to finish my project soon. Thank you so much

Comment: Can you check if there anything found for 'Pinjam::find($id);'

Comment: Yes i can, the record was successfully found

Comment: Can you show the Modal for the table 'tb_peminjaman'. specially what is the primary key?

Comment: Please, show you tb_peminjaman table.

Comment: The record was successfully found using get method, but idk why the put method read column named "tb_peminjaman" where it supposed to be a table name

Comment: https://files.fm/u/qyjmkegt#/view/table.PNG

Comment: Here is my **Pinjam.php**

`<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pinjam extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'tb_peminjaman';
    protected $fillable = ['ketua_kegiatan','lab','level','tanggal_mulai','tanggal_selesai','jam_mulai','jam_selesai','daftar_nama','keperluan','kontak_ketua','app_laboran','app_kalab','app_kajur','app_pudir'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}`

Comment: The primary key of my table is "no_pengajuan" which I set it to auto increment in my database

Comment: Column notfound **id**, so add to your Model protected $primaryKey = 'no_pengajuan';

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much for helping me Mr.Med ZAIRI ... I thought at first its because of the tb_peminjaman... so sorry, my bad... It works for me! Thanks Again!